# Cl0sed Circle Drawing Simple

Tags: recursion, addition

I'm trying to add these 2 binary. I'm attempting to write a function  that adds two binary numbers . I'm trying to get it to add one pair of bits. I'm not sure how to carry the extra bits though. Here is what I have programmed:

But my index is out of range and I'm not sure how to carry bits. I've been thinking that I should call the function a second time using recursion to add in the bits but I don't know how to implement it. Can anyone tell me how to edit my existing code so that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def add_binary(s1, s2):
    def sub(s1, s2, carry):
        if s1 or s2 or carry:
            add1 = (int(s1[-1]) if s1 else 0) + (int(s2[-1]) if s2 else 0) + carry
            return sub(s1[:-1], s2[:-1], add1//2) + str(add1%2)
        else:
            return ""
    return sub(s1, s2, 0)
```

**EDIT** more explicit version:

```
def add_binary(s1, s2):

    def sub(s1, s2, carry):
        if s1 != ""  or s2 != ""  or carry != 0:
            if s1 == "":
                s1 = "0"
            if s2 == "":
                s2 = "0"
            add1 = int(s1[-1]) + int(s2[-1]) + carry
            return sub(s1[:-1], s2[:-1], add1//2) + str(add1%2)
        else:
            return ""

    return sub(s1, s2, 0)
```

Comment: I don't think that makes sense. What part of my solution is unclear or problematic?

Comment: In every recursion you have a base case, which specifies when to stop recursing. Here, the condition to stop is that s1 is empty and s2 is empty and carry is 0. But this looks clumsier in code, so I reversed the condition: if either s1 is not "", or s2 is not "", or carry is not 0, then do something.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_binary(s1, s2, carry=0):
    if not s1:
        if not carry: return s2
        else: return '1'*carry + s2
    if not s2:
        if not carry: return s1
        else: return '1'*carry + s1
    add = int(s1[-1])+int(s2[-1]) + carry
    carry = add and not add%2
    return add_binary(s1[:-1], s2[:-1], carry) + str(add%2)
```

Output:

```
In [16]: add_binary('10101', '10101')
Out[16]: '101010'

In [17]: add_binary('11', '')
Out[17]: '11'
```

Comment: @DonaldWang: it's a lot cleaner this way, and the function can be called with only one argument. So I wouldn't worry too much about changing it further

Comment: @DonaldWang: why don't you try playing around with my code for a while, and make new post or edit your current one, to ask for further help?

Comment: @DonaldWang: I tried briefly, and couldn't quite get it to work. Hence my hesitation. Further, I really need to get back to my work, which is why I am unable to help out much more at the moment. This is why I recommended making a new post with a new attempt - so that someone cleverer than me can help out ;]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather different approach that seems also to fit the problem statement.

```
digits = {('1','1'):'10',('1','0'):'01',('0','1'):'01',('0','0'):'00'}

def add_ones(d1d2):
  return digits[d1d2]

def add_binary(s1, s2):
  if not '1' in s1: return s2
  if not '1' in s2: return s1
  while (len(s1)>len(s2)):
    s1 = '0' + s1
  while (len(s2)>len(s1)):
    s2 = '0' + s2
  c = []  #carries
  p = ['0']  #places
  for d1d2 in zip(s1,s2):
      ci, pi = add_ones(d1d2)
      c.append(ci)
      p.append(pi)
  c.append('0')
  p = ''.join(p)
  c = ''.join(c)
  return add_binary(p,c)
```